# Does a plasma with plasma frequency $\omega_p$ generate photons of the same frequency?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, plasma-physics

I know that photon emission in plasma results in a change of energy level of the electrons from excited or ionised atoms. However, I saw that photons of 13eV were created in a helium plasma, but this energy doesn't correpsond to any of the energy transitions of helium. The plasma frequency was about $3e9$ MHz, which does correspond to 13eV photons. I'm now wondering how plasma frequency can generate photons by itself. Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: there is much more than " change of energy level of the electrons from excited or ionised atoms" happening in a plasma, and one has to define **what** plasma one is talking about. For example in tokamaks "Radiation from relativistic runaway electrons is considered as a source for plasma frequency radiation in tokamaks. Two specific mechanisms, Cerenkov emission and radiation produced by nonlinear coupling of plasma and acoustic waves, are studied"  https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.863589

Comment: It generates electric fields that oscillate at that frequency, because the electrons are oscillating at that frequency and the ions cannot keep up.  As for the frequency of the photons communicating the electric field, I am not sure, to be honest.  Doesn't hat have to do with the energy of the photons, i.e., E = $\hbar \omega$?  So do we start from the energy of the electric field and then determine the frequency or start with the frequency and determine the energy...  Good question, I haven't thought of that...